# Satisfying multiple WHERE criteria via join table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table, `products`, and another, `categories`. The two are associated by `products_categories`. A product can appear in multiple categories.

What I'm trying to do is non-redundantly return results that satisfy all criteria. Example:

```
 SELECT *
  FROM products as p
  JOIN products_categories AS pc 
    ON p.PRODUCTID = pc.productid
  JOIN categories AS c 
    ON c.id = pc.category
 WHERE c.category = 'All Products' 
   AND c.category = 'On Sale' 
   AND c.category = 'Active'
 GROUP 
    BY p.PRODUCTID
```

Obviously, I'm going wrong somewhere. In this case, I want to return anything that's in the `All Products`, `On Sale`, and `Active` categories.

Comment: You could also try WHERE c.category IN ('All Products', 'On Sale', 'Active')

Comment: I think you want: `SELECT * FROM members WHERE membership_number IN (1,2,3);` Just an example showing the use of the IN keyword.

Comment: @icydemon Great minds... right?

Comment: @RobMoll just an sql noob here but IN and BETWEEN have saved me a ton of times

Comment: Hmm... using IN seems to be returning results that are not in all three criteria but may be in one.

Comment: You don't want to "return results that satisfy all criteria". You want to return all results that satisfy one of the criteria. ( Or at least one or at most one--you're not clear.) (And you're not clear about what "results" means either.) Returning rows that satisfy P and returning rows that satisfy Q means returning rows that satisfy P OR Q. PS This is a faq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all `AND`s to `OR`s in the `WHERE` clause and if you want products that belong in all 3 categories add a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT p.PRODUCTID
FROM products as p
JOIN products_categories AS pc ON p.PRODUCTID = pc.productid
JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = pc.category
WHERE c.category = 'All Products' OR c.category = 'On Sale' OR c.category = 'Active'
GROUP BY p.PRODUCTID
HAVING COUNT(c.id) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have stated, there maybe occasions where there are 1, 2, or 3 WHERE criteria.

Comment: If you mean that you may want products belonging in 2 categories, then change to `HAVING COUNT(c.id) = 2`

Comment: This works if I use WHERE/IN instead of OR. Thanks.

Comment: This works with ORs also. IN is just a shortcut of all the ORs.

Comment: @BenjaminAllison the `3` indicates how many matches you want. If you want it to match all items in the list, the number should indicate the number of items in the list; if you want say "two or more items in the list" you can use `>= 2` rather than `= number of items in list`. _Sidenote: If `products_categories` can have non-unique product-category combinations, the `COUNT(` needs to be `COUNT(DISTINCT`_

Answer (score 1):

With the `AND`ed conditions on `category`, there is no row that will satisfy both conditions... if there's a row that has `category = 'Active'` we know that the test `category = 'On Sale'` is going to evaluate to FALSE. (So if we "and" those two conditions, we get FALSE.)

So, we want to `OR` those conditions, to get rows that satisfy any of the conditions.

To get `products` that are associated with all three categories, we can do something like this

We can do something like this:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM products p
  JOIN ( -- productid associated with all three categories
         SELECT pc.productid 
           FROM products_categories pc
           JOIN categories c 
             ON c.id = pc.category
          WHERE (  c.category = 'All Products' 
                OR c.category = 'On Sale'
                OR c.category = 'Active'
                )
         GROUP
            BY pc.productid
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.category) = 3
      ) n
   ON n.productid = p.productid
ORDER
   BY p.productid
```

Note also that there is shorthand substitute for those `OR`'d equality tests on `category`

```
         WHERE c.category IN ('All Products','On Sale','Active')
```